# Get turn angle to position on coordinate map?

Tags: python, math, geometry, robotics

I'm trying to get a robot to turn to face another robot, based on their respective coordinates on a global coordinate map.

This is the code I wrote, but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
def calcAngleToCoords(self, curAngle, curPosition, targPosition):
    retVal = False

    if type(curPosition) is list and type(targPosition) is list:
        x_1, y_1 = curPosition
        x_2, y_2 = targPosition
        # Sets origin coordinate to zero
        x_2 = x_2 - x_1
        y_2 = y_2 - y_1

        radius = math.sqrt(y_2 ** 2 + x_2 ** 2) # Pythagorean Thereom, a^2 + b^2 = c^2 | Radius = c, y_2 = a, x_2 = b
        angle = curAngle * (math.pi / 180)

        x_1 = radius * math.cos(angle)
        y_1 = radius * math.sin(angle)

        turnArc = math.atan( (y_1 - y_2) / (x_2 - x_1) ) * (180 / math.pi)

        retVal = turnArc
        # TODO: Check to see if the angle is always clockwise.
    else:
        raise TypeError("Invalid parameter types. Requires two lists.")

    return(retVal)
```

Can any one tell me a better way to do this or what I'm doing wrong? It's for a project I'm working on and the deadline is coming up really soon so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to calculate radius

```
    x_2 = x_2 - x_1
    y_2 = y_2 - y_1
    angle = curAngle * (math.pi / 180)
    dx = math.cos(angle)
    dy = math.sin(angle)
    turnArc = math.atan2(x_2 * dy - y_2 * dx,  x_2 * dx + y_2 * dy ) * (180 / math.pi)
```

Note using of atan2 function, that returns angle between -pi and pi. It correctly determines rotation direction and finds the shortest turn. If you need to rotate in clockwise direction only, add 180 if turnArc is negative

Comment: Thanks, but I'm somewhat confused. You said there is no need to calculate radius but then you included radius in your code?